# Ways to access and download the metadata of OpenStreetMaps

Tags: data, openstreetmap, metadata

Does anyone know if there are any good methods or apps to access and download the metadata of OSM from desktop?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "metadata of OSM"? The history of objects?  The source tag?

Comment: please expand on what information - metadata

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't make the term metadata clear. What I want is actually the time when the data uploaded by specific users was downloaded and edited. Thank you very much for your kind reminding.

Answer (score 3):

http://planet.openstreetmap.org has a changeset file you can download, which includes information about each change made to the database. Look for changesets-latest.osm.bz2.

Answer (score 1):

If by "metadata" you mean vector data, then there are several ways to do it. But it depends on your needs.

These two ways allow you to specify a map area you're interested in (but the size of the area *is* limited):

1. http://www.openstreetmap.org/export - choose "OpenStreetMap XML Data"
2. [Using Maperitive](http://braincrunch.tumblr.com/post/9947074703/maperitive-tutorial-generating-osm-map-for-adobe) (see the first two steps).

If you need the whole world, download the [planet.osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm). You will however need a lot of HW resources, so good luck with that.

There are also extracts for countries/parts of countries on [Geofabrik](http://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html) and [Cloudmade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. But what I really mean about the term metadata is data about data which can be information about contributors who upload and edit the map. And here what I specially concern about is the time data which describes the uploading, editing and downloading time of the data. Still, as an OSM newie, I have been benefited a lot from your answers about vector data retrieving techniques.

Comment: @IgorBrejc Were you referring to GPS Coordinates from vector data? Or were you specifically referring to Vector Data instead of Raster Data as per this [Difference between Raster and Vector Data](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27089/80837)  I apologize in advance, if this seems confusing or what I am saying may not make sense. I am very new to this space, and am trying to understand it better. From what I understand, Raster is a more efficient way of getting GPS "metadata" the underlying coordinates of (GPS) in my case, that help depict an area on a map that can be linked to a map.

Answer (score 1):

For inspiration, check out the blog posting "OpenStreetMap: a Year of Edits" by Derick Rethans (http://drck.me/osmyoe11-9nz). He discusses how he got hold of the changes in the OSM data set that happened in 2011 and how he made a beautiful video out of it. Intrigued to learn what use you are investiging!