# Failed to execute floating raster to integer raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

[image]

im facing a problem in converting Floating to Integer Raster by using"spatial analyst tools (arc toolbox) > math > Int" . However, it shows warning of "error ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error. Failed to execute (Int)." * as shown in the attached file * . i've used both raster calculator method and spatial analyst tools in arctoolbox but still failed. how to overcome this problem ?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if Arc's Integer raster is a 16-bit short, 32-bit int or 64-bit long, or whether they are signed ints or not, but with that error it's possible that your raster contains values that lie outside the range of possible values. For example, a signed 16-bit int can only hold the values between -32768 and 32767. That's a fairly narrow range! A 32-bit int however can hold a much larger range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. Do you have an incredibly large value in the floating point raster?

Comment: @WhiteboxDev yes, the value for floating extremely large (example:11.70007324) . is there a way to reduce the floating point?

Comment: 11.70007324 doesn't sound like that large a value. It fits well within the range of any integer data type. I'm talking about a number that is in the millions or billions (positive or negative). Do you have anything like that? What are your minimum and maximum values in the raster?

Comment: @WhiteboxDev i really need to convert the floating raster to integer so that i can proceed to the step for conversion of "raster to feature" in spatial analyst.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev oh, dont have. all the value is within that range of (0-min up to 186.5429993-max)

Comment: Okay, it's not a value range problem then. Is your 'slope of tin' layer above a raster or vector? The Int tool is expecting a raster I believe.

Comment: @WhiteboxDev it is a raster file, with 32bit, floating point.. i need to convert this "slope of tin" to the vector. however when im trying to convert "raster to feature" . it shows the warning of " ...is a floating raster , the input dataset must be integer " . then when i try to convert it to integer . it shows the warning as the picture above .

Answer (score 1):

Given your application of vectorizing the raster triangular facets of a slope field derived from a TIN, I would suggest the following alternative workflow. The benefit of this approach is that you will not lose information about the slope of triangular facets through rounding or truncation. I should note that the assumes you have **Spatial Analyst**. First, use the **Region Group** tool to assign unique integer ID values to your slope raster. Because your triangular facets are planes, they contain only one value, which will allow this method to work well. Then vectorize the resulting clumped image. Once you've vectorized, you can then add a 'Slope' field to the vector's attribute table using the **Zonal statistics** tool.

Comment: ive tried the the steps above , however it shows warning output " failed execution region (group)" . is there something wrong with my spatial analyst toolboxes ?

Comment: @RaimyHaidar What is the data format of your input raster? What's the file extension? That is not a tool that should fail on such a small raster with so few groups. How large is the raster (rows and columns) and how much RAM does your system have?

Comment: ( Data type : file system raster , Raster : tingrid2 , source type : continous , pixel type : 32 bit , noData value : -3.4028235e+038 ) ...it is a group of file in the folder of tingrid2 , which it is created from the output of spatial analyst > surface analysis > slope ( which the slope input is the 'tin' file with specified contours ) ....ram of my dekstop is 4gb. im sorry, what u mean by 'how large of raster (rows and columns) "

Comment: @RaimyHaidar Okay 4GB is really not much. If your raster is larger than about 500Mb this may be the problem. How large is it?

Comment: it's small. the raster file is 329kb .

Comment: basically, im try to convert it to vector as i need to proceed to the next step of my analysis . which involving the union of "multiple buffer" file with  "slope of tin " ..is there any significant different if i dint change both file to vector ?basically what is the critical difference between raster and vector file? sorry to ask, im quite beginner , im just following the steps from the source

Comment: @RaimyHaidar We're all beginners at some point! To answer your question, yes, there is a massive difference between the raster and vector data models and this can profoundly affect your workflow. Take a look at this question for more ideas of how this works: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57142/what-is-the-difference-between-vector-and-raster-data-models