# Under what situation do we use Rasterisation or Vectorisation?

Tags: rasterization, vectorization

As mention in the title, Rasterisation is the conversion of vector maps to raster grid. While Vectorisation is the conversion of raster grids to vector maps but under what situation would we use these?

Raster maps are better at continuous data,
Vector maps are better at discreet data.

What is the point Rasterisation or Vectorisation, for example if raster map are better at continuous data but you are trying to force it into a vector map.

Comment: A paper map may be scanned to create an digital image. You then may want to vectorize it to capture the features that make more sense as vector data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster data is only as sharp as the grid size that you are using.  To try and represent something like a Road or River as a Raster would be be faulty as is it will give the raster value to the entire grid where as the entire grid may not actually be that value (Say you are using 10m raster grids, and 51% of the grid is a type of soil, that will cause the entire raster to be represented as that soil type when that is not actually the case)  There are many other reasons to use one over the other but I wont list them, rather I will link you to them below.

Here is a list of advantages and disadvantages of each type

http://bgis.sanbi.org/gis-primer/page_19.htm

[What are Raster and Vector data in GIS and when to use?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/what-are-raster-and-vector-data-in-gis-and-when-to-use)