# Placing coordinates on a topographic map

Tags: qgis, cartography, topography

I am using QGIS for the first time. I want a topographic map with coordinates of locations. I have the SRTM data for the area of my interest. Using the following link I am able to get the topographic map. http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/topography/
Now I want to add the locations along with the names (not just points). I tried various ways but I havn't got any clue on how to do that. Could anyone tell me how can this be done? Also, is it possible to combine this topographic map with the shapefile, so that I have a map with terrain information, coordinates and boundary of the area?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Is the question how place points and display label? Of course you can SRTM data and Shapefiles. What have you tried yet?

Comment: I guess you have your locations in a shape file. Did you succeed at displaying the points of your shape file? Displaying the names is a matter of putting labels, please provide the information you have so far in your shape file do you have "name" for instance?. Combining information of two sources (the srtm and your shape file) is mainly linked with projections and coordinate system, if they are in the same system it is easy and you do not even realize it, but if they ar in different system, you need to know both systems and reproject one of them (also very easy in Qgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is simply create labels for a new Shapefile that you create to label your points of interest. Try doing the following:

1. Go to Layer -> Create Layer -> New Shapefile Layer
2. Create a "Point" layer using a WPSG:4326, WTG84 Coordinate Reference System (CRS, the default choice)
3. Add a field called "site_name" (or whatever you choose) of the Text data type and length appropriate for your names
4. Right click your new layer in the Layers Panel and "Toggle Editing"
5. Find the "Add Feature" icon in the toolbar on top and click to add your new site (the "ID" can just be a serial number like 1, 2, 3, etc...)
6. Right click your new layer in the Layers Panel and "Toggle Editing" to save your edits
7. Right click your new layer in the "Layers Panel" and select "Properties"
8. Select Labels in the left column and on the top dropdown menu pick "Show labels for this layer"
9. Set "Label with", right below the dropdown menu to "site_name"
10. Click OK and your map should now have a label that looks like this image[image: site with label]. You can customize the label with buffers, fonts, and colors in the previous menu.

To answer your second question, it's not possible to have different types of geographic feature types (e.g. points, polygons) in the same Shapefile. You have to break them up into separate files. Also, Shapefiles are for vector data and your terrain data is going to be a raster format and one of many different raster data types. See this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/what-are-raster-and-vector-data-in-gis-and-when-to-use) for a good definition of the two. A good way to organize your related GIS files is to simply save them in a project file in QGIS (the files created when you do a regular old "Save").