# Merging Shapefile with Image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, image

QGIS version 3.2.1

Windows 10

Project File on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/Coffee/blob/master/coffeeproject.qgz)

Shape files on [Github](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/Coffee/tree/master/coffee)

---

I am trying to create shapefile from coffee cup image.

The actual coffee should be the shapefile.

However I would like the background of shapefile to be original coffeecup.

Here is original coffee image

[image]

Here is how I'd wish shapefile to look like (the green polygon has shape properties). Remaining shapefile should have coffee cup and saucer as original image instead of additional polygon.

[image]

Both coffee image and created shapefile are the layers. When I unselect coffee image I get this

[image]

Perhaps there is a way to merge the image into the shapefile?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "background of shapefile to be original coffeecup." Do you want to add the coffee cup to the shapefile as an additional polygon?

Comment: @csk Remaining coffee cup should be original image, not additional polygon,

Comment: shape-file is as you know a vector-format (poly or line or point), you can "merge" it with a raster (=picture), raster only can be a seperate layer in the background. why not put the (green) poly-shapefile on top of the background-raster?

Comment: @Kurt Silly question but how would I "merge" it. I created the raster, selected it along with shape file, saved as new shapefile, but only the polygon appears. Here is updated shapefile, https://github.com/ArtieLadie/Coffee/tree/master/coffee_merge. Please assist.

Comment: @Kurt I see option for Raster > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster), but it doesn't convert to shapefile

Comment: Polygonize (Raster to Vector) and afterwards export  the layer as shapefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read up on the difference between raster and vector data:

[What are Raster and Vector data in GIS and when to use?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/what-are-raster-and-vector-data-in-gis-and-when-to-use)

The image is raster data. The shapefile is vector data. To combine them, first convert them to the same type. Either [rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html) the polygon, or [polygonize](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/polygonize.html) the image.

Once the two files are the same data type, you can combine them. Please refer to the appropriate section of the QGIS manual for further instructions:

- [Working with Vector Data](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/index.html)
- [Working with Raster Data](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for this resource. Will study this and follow up.

Comment: Please assist with this question, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292880/how-to-convert-raster-image-to-shapefile-without-flipping-it-upside-down